# Regular expression search replace in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext2

I'm looking to do search replace with regular expressions in Sublime Text 2. The [documentation on this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html#regular-expressions) is rather anemic. Specifically, I want to do a replace on groups, so something like converting this text:

`Hello my name is bob`

And this search term:

Find what: `my name is (\w)+`

Replace with: `my name used to be $(1)`

The search term works just fine but I can't figure out a way to actually do a replace using the regexp group.

Answer (score 659, accepted):

Usually a back-reference is either `$1` or `\1` (backslash one) for the first capture group (the first match of a pattern in parentheses), and indeed Sublime supports both syntaxes. So try:

```
my name used to be \1
```

or

```
my name used to be $1
```

Also note that your original capture pattern:

```
my name is (\w)+
```

is incorrect and will only capture the final letter of the name rather than the whole name. You should use the following pattern to capture all of the letters of the name:

```
my name is (\w+)
```

Comment: No, $0 is not used as a back-reference in a regular expression (because `\0` equals the null character, and `\0ddd` is used as an escape for a character with code point ddd). However, `$0` does seem to be used in Sublime2 as an "exit mark" according to [this page](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/snippets.html?highlight=$0) (though I'm having trouble finding enough examples to work out exactly how an exit mark is used in Sublime2).

Comment: The exit mark `$0` is used in Sublime Text 2/3 to place the cursor on exit from a snippet expansion. [More on snippets](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/snippets.html?highlight=snippets).

Comment: $0 still works for backreferencing the entire expression in Sublime Text 2

Comment: `$0` is the entire regex match; `$1` is the first capture group.

Comment: `$0` worked for me in Sublime 3 to get the whole matched expression. I had a capturing group around the whole regex and a nested capturing group in the middle, and `$1` was referencing the internal capturing group, which is strange because I thought capturing groups were ordered by opening parentheses. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: $0 worked for me in Sublime 3 - matching a whole, different expression.

Comment: Using parentheses is essential in the search expression to address the groups as mentioned by Hrvoje Golcic.

Comment: Don't forget to escape special characters with a back slash .ie `\(` to escape an opening bracket

Comment: Is it possible to replace with either or capturing group?
If i have 5 capturing groups, of which group 1 and 2 are common, group 3 and 4 come together but are option against group 5. For example, i'd like to replace with
`$1, $2, (if $3, then $3$4 else $5)`

Just realized i could just do
`$1, $2, $3$4$5` for my use case, and it should just work fine

Answer (score 110):

By the way, in the question above:

For:

```
Hello, my name is bob
```

Find part:

```
my name is (\w)+
```

With replace part:

```
my name used to be \1
```

Would return:

```
Hello, my name used to be b
```

Change find part to:

```
my name is (\w+)
```

And replace will be what you expect:

```
Hello, my name used to be bob
```

While (\w)+ will match "bob", it is not the grouping you want for replacement.

Answer (score 77):

> Important: Use the `( )` parentheses in your search string

While the previous answer is correct there is an important thing to emphasize! All the **matched segments in your search string** that you want to use in your **replacement string** must be **enclosed by `( )` parentheses**, otherwise these matched segments won't be accessible to defined variables such as `$1`, `$2` or `\1`, `\2` etc.

For example we want to replace 'em' with 'px' but preserve the digit values:

```css
    margin: 10em;  /* Expected: margin: 10px */
    margin: 2em;   /* Expected: margin: 2px */
```

- Replacement string: `margin: $1px` or `margin: \1px`
- Search string (CORRECT): `margin: ([0-9]*)em` // with parentheses
- Search string (INCORRECT): `margin: [0-9]*em`

---

**CORRECT CASE EXAMPLE:** Using `margin: ([0-9]*)em` search string (with parentheses). Enclose the desired matched segment (e.g. `$1` or `\1`) by `( )` parentheses as following:

- Find: `margin: ([0-9]*)em` (with parentheses)
- Replace to: `margin: $1px` or `margin: \1px`
- Result:

```css
    margin: 10px;
    margin: 2px;
```

---

**INCORRECT CASE EXAMPLE:** Using `margin: [0-9]*em` search string (without parentheses). The following regex pattern will match the desired lines but matched segments will not be available in replaced string as variables such as `$1` or `\1`:

- Find: `margin: [0-9]*em` (without parentheses)
- Replace to: `margin: $1px` or `margin: \1px`
- Result:

```css
    margin: px; /* `$1` is undefined */
    margin: px; /* `$1` is undefined */
```

Comment: Thank you, this answer really points out a interesting fact that resolved my problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  With (), I can do the replace with \1 in Sublime 3.

Answer (score 33):

Note that if you use more than 9 capture groups you have to use the syntax `${10}`.

`$10` or `\10` or `\{10}` will **not** work.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful for me to replace and add a number to the end of the captured group, e.g. to append a `1` to the second capture group you need to use braces like `${2}1`; $21 refers to the 21st capture group, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I was trying to replace $1 to $1 and 0 and but not $10. Your answer solved this problem. Now I used ${1}0 and I added 0 . Thanks..

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation's article on Search and Replace](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html), it looks like `+(.+)` is the capture group you might want... but I personally used `(.*)` and it worked well. To REPLACE in the way you are saying, you might like this [conversation in the forums](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-replace-not-find-using-regex/13134/4), specifically [this post](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-to-replace-not-find-using-regex/13134/4) which says to simply use `$1` to use the first captured group.

**And since pictures are better than words...**

**Before:**
[image: before find/replace]

**After:**
[image: after find/replace]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem:

Many strigs with this pattern like in
Don Jo`s6` went (correct was Don Jo`sé` went)

I used this tool:
https://coding.tools/regex-replace

Regular Expression: `([a-z])6`

Replace To: `$1é`

Click on the "Regex Replace" Button.
Result:

Don Jo`sé` went

It also works in Google Sheets.