# Sublime Text 2 - Regular Expression Find and Replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I am looking for a solution to find and replace the formatting of many prices within one of my documents.

I currently have prices that are formatting like so: **$60** and would like to change the formatting to: **60 $**

The following 'Find What' works to find the first format `\$\d{0,2}` but not too sure about what to 'Replace With'.

Is there a way to preserve the number?

Thank you.

Comment: Found a solution... \$(\d+) then replace with \1$

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

find: `\$(\d{0,2})`
replace: `\1 $`

Answer (score 1):

Option+Cmd+F:

Place into the find field:

```
\$([0-9]{0,2})
```

Place into the replace field:

```
\1 \$
```

The backslash + number indicated which capture group to place in there.

Comment: see this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2

Comment: I saw that post - found it overly complex for what I wanted to do. thanks