# Matching with a regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext2

I have a string like:

```
{
    { SomeTextNoQuotes, "Some Text's", "Some Text" },
    { SomeTextNoQuotes, "Some Text's", "Some Text" },
    { SomeTextNoQuotes, "Some Text's", "Some Text" },
    { SomeTextNoQuotes, "Some Text's", "Some Text" },
    { SomeTextNoQuotes, "Some Text's", "Some Text" },
}
```

How can I match the last `, "Some Text"` of each row, just before the `}`?
By the way, this is in Sublime Text that I'm trying to do it. The values are not consistent like I have them here, and I have a few hundred lines to replace on.

I tried `, ".*"` but that matches `, "Some Text's, "Some Text"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ways you could go about this.

Option `#1` we match the first set and then capture the second including the comma in group `\1` or `$1`

```
"[^"]*"(, "[^"]*")
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/rG3xS4)

Option `#2` we use a look ahead to find that matched set.

```
, "[^"]*"(?= \})
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/vY8kD6)

Option `#3` we can match the whole string and our match is included in capture group `\1` or `$1`

```
\{[\S\s]*?(,\s+"[^"]*")\s+\}
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/jN5iW2)

Comment: #2 worked perfect, not sure how to use groups in sublimes replace. But a big +1 for those live demos and that site, I've never seen it before but it looks like a great way to finally learn regexs!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2 for future reference on capture groups with replacing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Sublime Text, but if it supports lookaheads, `, ".[^"]*"(?= })` should do the trick.

Comment: @今草顿웃: No, I can't, since OP explicitly wants it included in the match.

Comment: This didn't quite work, however escaping the } did the trick. `, ".[^"]*"(?= \})`.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following should work (using lookahead):

```
("Some Text")(?= \}\,)
```

The captured text will be found in the first matched group

Link to **[Fiddle](http://regexr.com?36olf)**

Comment: This didn't work seeing as I stated, `The values are not consistent like I have them here`. Thanks anyway. :)