# Escaping parentheses in code that needs to be searched and replaced (Sublime Text2)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, sublimetext2, console.log

I know [how to search and replace strings with Sublime Text2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2) but not when escape characters are used.

For the following javascript code can someone tell me how to escape the parentheses here?

```
if(PRODUCTION) console.log("hello world");

var log=function(message){
   if(!PRODUCTION) console.log(message);
};
```

The following does **not** work but seems close to being right:

*find:* `if(PRODUCTION) console.log("(\w+)");`

*replace:* `log($1);`

The ultimate goal is to only do console logging if in a development and not a production environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape special characters with backslash:

Find: `if\(PRODUCTION\) console.log\((".+?")\);`

Replace: `log($1)`

Note that `\w+` won't match `hello world`, because `\w` doesn't match space. I've changed it to `.+?` so it will match anything until the matching doublequote.

Comment: I know this bit is in the OP's code, but a little improvement could be removing the quotes so any call to console log gets replaced: `console.log\((.+?)\)` (i.e. console.log(someVar); )