# Regex for find Replace

Tags: java, regex, sublimetext2

In context of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2) I want to do the following changes:

**Find**:

> funcA(param0,param1,param2,param3);

**Replace**:

```
if(isTrue)
    funcB(param0,funcC(param1,param2,param3));
```

funcA can have any number of parameters besides param0.How can it be done?For simplicity **ignore the base case** i.e when param pass to funcA is only param0.

**funcA** is:

```
public void funcA(String param0,Object... params)
```

**funcC** is:

```
public void funcB(Object... params).
```

EDIT:

The parameters(param1,param2..) are just string containing alphabets.

Comment: What about nested brackets e.g. `funcA(param0,param1.trim(), param2, param3.size());` etc?

Comment: no.they are for sure just alphabets(names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search regex:

```
^ *funcA *\(([^,\s;)]*) *(?:, *([^)\;]+))?
```

Replacement Pattern:

```
if(isTrue) funcB($1, funcC($2)
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/tO8qG1/7)

Comment: Hi,this looks good.But can you make the regex first find funcA.Here it assumes that the given line is calling funcA.I have to do the replacement in my code

Comment: Thanks.It handle the base case also.

Comment: This isn't working for the situation below.            funcA(param0);
funcA(param0,param1,param2,param3);http://regex101.com/r/tO8qG1/3

Comment: But you wrote: `For simplicity ignore the base case` What do you want `funcA(param0);` to be replaced by?

Comment: Though this is what I asked for it will be great if you can provide  regex for the base class also. http://regex101.com/r/tO8qG1/6 Here the 4th line should get converted to if(isTrue) funcB(param0,funcC())