# Extract and Create Property in JSON file with RegEx

Tags: json, regex, replace, find, sublimetext3

I have the following [JSON file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/e91b46836491d1841c276fe0751080c3/raw/ec2318fcd8a49c7bf1bdb4e6cdff4248ed33207f/original.json). Dotted across the file is the following:

```
"properties": {
    "Name": "Darlington",
    "Description": "<br><br><br> <table border=\"1\" padding=\"0\"> <tr><td>CCGcode</td><td>00C</td></tr> <tr><td>CCGname_short</td><td>Darlington</td></tr>"
}
```

Using RegEx, I would like to extract the CCG Code property and add it back in so that the above becomes:

```
"properties": {
    "Name": "Darlington",
    "CCGcode": "00C",
    "Description": "<br><br><br> <table border=\"1\" padding=\"0\"> <tr><td>CCGcode</td><td>00C</td></tr> <tr><td>CCGname_short</td><td>Darlington</td></tr>"
}
```

I've tried all sorts and I just can't get it to work. I am using Sublime Text.

```
^("Description":").*?<td>CCGcode<\/td><td>([^<>\n]*).*$
```

The above selects the code, but not sure how I can get it to create the property.

Comment: *What* have you tried?

Comment: updated Q. Thanks @ClasG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
( *)"Description".*?CCGcode.*?<td>([^<]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wC8pX2/1)

This one for `sublimetext3`

Find what:

```
( *)("Description".*?CCGcode.*?<td>)([^<]+)
```

Replace with:

```
\1"CCGcode": "\3",\n\1\2
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fO7pO0/1)

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simpel, but not so elegant, solution. Replace

```
"Description":.*?<td>CCGcode<\/td><td>([A-Z\d]*)<\/td>
```

with

```
"CCGCode":"\1",\n    \0
```

Don't know how *Sublime* handles replacements, but you may have to change the replacing `\0` and `\1` to something else - e.g. `$0` and `$1`.

What it does is to find the `Description` entry and the following `CCGCode` entry, capturing the code into capture group 1.

Then replace capture group 0 - the whole matched text, with the new `CCGCode` JSON tag **plus** the original text.

It's a pretty fragile solution, but it works for your sample case.

[Check out example at regex101.](https://regex101.com/r/nL4dS8/2)

Regards

Comment: [Check this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2). Apparently bot `\1` and `$1` should work :)

Comment: This works too, but `(00C)` needed to be generalised so that it applied to all `CCGcodes`. +1 for explanation. Thank You

Comment: Of course, sloppiness from my side. That was the intention ;) Corrected the answer.