# How to replace html tags but keep the text in between?

Tags: html, regex, text-editor

I'd like to keep the text in between the span tags. But there's something wrong with the replace expression...

I'm using Calibre text editor.

```
    Find:
    <span class="Heading3-strong">(.*?)</span>
    Replace:
    <strong>(.*?)</strong>

    Input:
    <span class="Heading3-strong">some text goes here</span>
    Output:
    <strong>some text goes here</strong>
```

Comment: Please add more context about what you mean when you say "the replace expression."

Comment: Even if it is "not recommended", I still need to use Regex.

Comment: Could you include some more information? What tool are you using to run the find & replace - some text editor, some programming language? What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: The replace is wrong, it must be `<strong>\1</strong>`.

Comment: Try <strong>\1</strong> not <strong>$1</strong> as Wiktor suggested. \1 is a common backreference to refer to the capture group defined in your find (.*?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression search replace in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2)

Answer (score 2):

The replacement pattern cannot be a regular exppression, it is a normal string that may contain backreferences in the form of `\n` where `n` is the group ID (they start from `1`).

So, in your case, you need to use

```
<strong>\1</strong>
```

where `\1` is the text matched with `(.*?)`.

See more about it [here](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/regexp.html#id15).