# I need a regular expression to replace a syntax

Tags: sublimetext3

I am new to sublime text3 but started to like working in it.

I am using its search and replace to achieve as below:

I have a list of hundreds of items like the below :

```
5149 : Kaliana
5427 : Kalo Chorio
5036 : Kalo Chorio Kapouti
5071 : Kalo Chorio Sleas
5466 : Kalopanagiotis
```

**But I want to replace these with**

```
5149-
5427-
5036-
5071-
5466-
```

So basically the colon and the words should be replaced by a hyphen(-) symbol

I tried few regular expressions.
for example : (?<=WORD).*$

but things aren't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression search replace in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2)

Comment: The way the problem is described and question is phrased it is unlikely going to contribute any value to SO. Next time divide and conquer your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried myself and finally got the expression that works for my requirement.

**In the find area type:**

```
 : [a-zA-Z\d" "]+
```

**And in the replace area type:**

```
-
```

This gives you the numbers followed by a hiphen and eliminating the words.