# Can I merge an .sql file that runs insert into and a Laravel factory seeder that creates dummy data on 2 only columns?

Tags: mysql, laravel, replace, migration, barcode

I have a factory file that creates dummy data for 2 columns: code & barcode. However, I wanted to run an .sql file that replaces data after I run the factory command. With that, I guess a merge will happen and might delete some records, or add new ones. Is that possible to merge the data instead. Like automatic mapping?

Here's the content of my .sql file:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.7.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1
-- Generation Time: Apr 23, 2021 at 12:14 PM
-- Server version: 10.1.28-MariaDB
-- PHP Version: 7.1.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `db_zachmatic`
--

--
-- Dumping data for table `products`
--

REPLACE INTO `products` (`id`, `code`, `name`, `description`, `unit`, `cost`, `srp`, `supplier`, `qty_on_hand`, `category`, `delivery_date`, `created_at`) VALUES
(12, 'P-824830', 'magnum-v', '45/90-17 MV-360 tube type tires only', 'Pieces', '', '1246', 'HH All Ventures', 3, 'Tires', '', ''),
(13, 'P-232033', 'magnum-v', '50/100-17 MV-360 tube type tire only', 'Select Product ', '', '1246', 'HH All Ventures', 1, 'Tires', '', ''),
(14, 'P-73032309', 'magnum-v', '60/90-17 MV-360 Tube Type Tire Only', 'Pieces', '', '1341', 'HH All Ventures', 0, 'Tires', '', ''),
(15, 'P-0022252', 'magnum-v', '45/90-17 MV-329 Tube Type with Tube', 'Pieces', '', '1120', 'HH All Ventures', 9, 'Tires', '', ''),
(16, 'P-323694', 'magnum-v', '50/100-17 MV-329 tube type with tube', 'Select Product ', '', '1120', 'HH All Ventures', 0, 'Tires', '', ''),
(17, 'P-023202', 'magnum-v', '60/90-17 MV-329 tube type with tube', 'Pieces', '', '1499', 'HH All Ventures', 0, 'Tires', '', ''),
(18, 'P-4729320', 'magnum-v', '70/90-17 MV-329 tube type with tube', 'Pieces', '', '1678', 'HH All Ventures', 0, 'Tires', '', ''),
(19, 'P-3020323', 'magnum-v', '120/70-13 MV-119C Tubeless', 'Pieces', '', '1829', 'HH All Ventures', 5, 'Tires', '', ''),
(20, 'P-3220830', 'magnum-v', '130/70-13 MV-119C tubeless', 'Pieces', '', '2062', 'HH All Ventures', 0, 'Tires', '', ''),

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `products`
--
ALTER TABLE `products` DROP COLUMN `id`;
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD COLUMN `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE FIRST;

--
-- Drop `code` column to delete old barcodes
-- then re-add `code` column, then add `barcode` column
--
ALTER TABLE `products` DROP COLUMN `code`;
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD COLUMN code VARCHAR(255) AFTER id;

--
-- Drop `delivery_date` column to delete old column
-- then re-add `delivery_date` column, then add `barcode` column
--
ALTER TABLE `products` DROP COLUMN `delivery_date`;
ALTER TABLE `products` ADD COLUMN delivery_date DATETIME;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Then my factory file:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Picqer;

class ProductFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Product::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        $code = $this->faker->bothify('PHZM-##########');
        $barcode = $this->generateBarcode($code);
        return [            
            'code' => $code,
            'barcode' => $barcode,
        ];
    }

    private function generateBarcode($code_to_convert) {
        $generator = new Picqer\Barcode\BarcodeGeneratorHTML();
        $barcode = $generator->getBarcode($code_to_convert, $generator::TYPE_CODE_128, 1, 15);
        return $barcode;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you must create seeder for running this script file like below:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class SqlFileSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $path = public_path('sql/File.sql');
        $sql = file_get_contents($path);
        DB::unprepared($sql);
    }

}
```

and inside another seeder that your factory calls, you run this seeder too after calling factory

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class FooSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Product::factory()->count(20)->create();
        $this->call([SqlFileSeeder::class]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works well! Just another question, is it possible to merge the saved data from this line:  `Product::factory()->count(20)->create();` and data from this line: `$this->call([SqlFileSeeder::class]);`

Comment: Like is there something like `factory()->count(20)->update();`

Comment: you're welcome. this method does not exist in factory class so you may probably do this for yourself, but I recommend take it easy just it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @alirezadp10 for the direction! I've managed to solve this by following his answer as well as exporting the `products` table in phpmyadmin with `Update` queries instead of default `Insert Into` as `custom`.

[Screenshot: Export as Custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iif3.png)

1. Then uncheck the following:

- Add DROP TABLE / TRIGGER statement
- Add CREATE VIEW statement

[Screenshot: Uncheck these settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usL4O.png)

2. Select Update on the `Function to use when dumping data`
   dropdown.

[Screenshot: Select Update on the dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdXqG.png)

3. Then press Go.

After that, I've just replaced the field values using some regex in Sublime Text 3.
Link: [Regular expression search replace in Sublime Text 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11819886/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime-text-2)

And renamed the fields to my needs. For @alirezadp10 answer to work, I've run `php artisan db:seed`.